# Fast random selection from short vectors in Julia

Tags: performance, random, julia

I have a simple function which appears at several places in my Julia code and is run millions of times inside a loop. The function essentially does `rand([1,-1,im,-im])`, that's, it picks one of four possible given values. I noticed that this function takes a substantial amount of time in my huge loop, so, I tried to write it in a slightly faster way like this:

```
function qpsk()
  temp1 = ifelse(rand(Bool), 1+0im, -1+0im)
  temp2 = ifelse(rand(Bool), 1+0im,  0+1im)
  temp1*temp2
end
```

Then, it is typically called like this:

```
sig = complex(zeros(N))
for i = 1:N
  sig[i] = qpsk()
end
```

Now, is there any way to further optimize this function, or use another faster method? Appreciate your help.

---

**Comments on current answers:**

The answer of @DanGetz (22 lines??) doesn't solve the problem, because at the moment, Julia is not as good at vectors as with explicit loops. Also, 
my simple, 1 line `qpsk2(s)` below, is about 2X faster than those "cryptic" 22 lines of code in the original answer by Dan (a vector is created, though, which adds more time).

But the question remains, why they 
didn't implement something like `qpsk1` below? and why my original `qpsk` with branching is more than 3X faster than the straightforward `qpsk4(s)` below?

I added more versions below to guide the discussion if more experienced people like to jump in.

```
qpsk1(s) = s[1+(rand(Int8)&3)]          # Blazingly fast
qpsk2(s) = s[1+rand(Bool)+2rand(Bool)]  # Very fast
qpsk3(s) = s[rand(1:4,1)]               # Compiler issue here?
qpsk4(s) = s[rand(1:4)]                 # Why slow?
qpsk5(s) = rand([s])                    # Ridiculously slow!!
function test_orig(n)                   # Test qpsk(), very fast(branching!), why?
  for i = 1:n
    qpsk()
  end
end

using StaticArrays
function test(func, n)                  # Test all qpsk1 --> qpsk5
  s = SVector(1,-1,im,-im)
  for i=1:n
    func(s)
  end
end

@time test(qpsk1,10^8)  0.554994 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
@time test(qpsk2,10^8)  0.755286 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
@time test(qpsk3,10^8) 13.431529 seconds (400 M allocations: 26.822 GiB, 20.68% gc time)
@time test(qpsk4,10^8)  2.520085 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
@time test(qpsk5,10^8) 10.881852 seconds (200 M allocations: 20.862 GiB, 19.76% gc time)
@time test_orig(10^8)   0.771778 seconds (5 allocations: 176 bytes)
@time nqpsk2(10^8);     1.402830 seconds (9 allocations: 1.490 GiB, 6.39% gc time)
```

Comment: Check out RandomNumbers.jl for faster RNGs. That could lead to much better performance just by making the rand call faster. Also, avoiding the branches can help. You can probably come up with some way that uses arithmetic instead of changes here.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas -- Thanks for the kind reply. I tried to avoid branching by using two tiny vectors `p`, `q` like this: `p = [1, -1];
  q = [1, im]` and `function qpsk2(p,q)
   p[rand(Bool)+1]*q[rand(Bool)+1]
end` but it is slightly worse than branching.

Comment: Don't use vectors. Those are mutable and will heap allocate. Use tuples or [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) instead and it will stack allocate.

Comment: I also wonder if extracting dibits from a block of random numbers might perform well for this application.

Comment: Regardless of speed, the nicest way to produce this vector is `im.^rand(0:3,N)`. It's also quite competitive with method in the question ;)

Comment: As an aside: *I don't mean to hurt the Julia community...* and *Doing science for more than 15 years now...* is not OK language. The Julia community I recognize respects all courteous people and is centered on trying to do good software and science.

Comment: The reason Julia cannot compile `rand(1:4)` to `1+rand(Int8)&3` is that at compile time Julia only knows the _type_ of the input, which is `UnitRange`. It does not know whether the input _value_ will be `1:4` or `-42:10^9`. It seems pretty reasonable that `rand(1:4)` is roughly 5x as slow, I don't understand why you are unhappy with that. The solution in `qpsk1` seems satisfactory, IMHO.

Comment: I _do_ think there is something to be said for providing _general_ fast random selection from small collections, and I've opened an issue at `StaticArrays.jl` requesting this for `rand(::SVector{N})`.

Comment: Two comments to the newly added tests: 1. why do `rand([s])`? I think you mean `rand(s)`. 2. `s[rand(1:4)]` is not ideomatic in Julia. It seems like a leftover from non-array-focused languages that focus on indexing. The julia syntax for this is `rand(s)`.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard Actually, since `s` here is a `StaticArray`, you will get surprising results from `rand(s)`. You have to do `s[rand(1:4)]`. I've made an issue about this: https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl/issues/277

Comment: @DNF Oh thanks a lot, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 6):

**Summary of answer**

```
[(-1)^b1*im^b2 for (b1,b2) in zip(rand!(BitVector(N)),rand!(BitVector(N)))]
```

generates a length N vector faster.

**Answer**

Calculating the random bits is the bulk of the work, so exploring Chris' idea from comments of using RandomNumbers.jl is worth a shot. Additionally, we can use @rickhg12hs's idea to extract more bits from each random number generated. Regardless, generating a block of values together is essential for better optimization.

For example, the following code (`nqpsk1` uses `qpsk` from the question as the baseline. `nqpsk2` is a suggested improvement):

```
function qpsk()
  temp1 = ifelse(rand(Bool), 1+0im, -1+0im)
  temp2 = ifelse(rand(Bool), 1+0im,  0+1im)
  temp1*temp2
end

nqpsk1(n::Int) = [qpsk() for i=1:n]

nqpsk2(n::Int) = begin
    res = zeros(Int,2*n)
    blocks = n >>> 4                 # use blocks of 16 values
    btail = n & 0x000000000000000f   # in case n is not a multiple of 16
    pos = 1
    @inbounds for i=1:blocks
        bits = rand(UInt32)          # get random bits for a whole block
        for j=1:16
            b1 = Bool(bits & 1)
            bits >>>= 1
            b2 = Bool(bits & 1)
            bits >>>= 1
            res[pos+b1] = (-1)^b2
            pos += 2
        end
    end
    @inbounds for i=1:btail
        res[pos+rand(Bool)] = (-1)^rand(Bool)
        pos += 2
    end
    return reinterpret(Complex{Int64},res)
end
```

achieved a >4x improvement on my setup (Julia 0.7):

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime nqpsk1(320);
  8.791 μs (323 allocations: 15.19 KiB)

julia> @btime nqpsk2(320);
  1.056 μs (3 allocations: 5.20 KiB)
```

**Update**

With only a modest compromise in speed (and some allocation), but much better looking code:

```
function nqpsk3(n::Int)
    res = zeros(Int,2n)
    rv1 = rand!(BitVector(n))
    rv2 = rand!(BitVector(n))
    @inbounds for (b1,b2,i) in zip(rv1,rv2,1:2:2n)
        res[i+b1] = (-1)^b2
    end
    return reinterpret(Complex{Int},res)
end
```

The benchmark:

```
julia> @btime nqpsk3(320);
  1.780 μs (11 allocations: 5.83 KiB)
```

**Addendum**

And the one-(wrapped)-line version, does OK (2.48 μs) too:

```
nqpsk4(n) = [(1+0im,-1+0im,0+im,0-im)[2b1+b2+1] for
  (b1,b2) in zip(rand!(BitVector(n)),rand!(BitVector(n)))]
```

Finally, the real one-line version (1.96 μs):

```
nqpsk5(n) = [(-1)^b1*im^b2 for (b1,b2) in zip(rand!(BitVector(n)),rand!(BitVector(n)))]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. Please see the comments above. Can this version be implemented for single values rather than blocks?

Comment: @Don From the comments added in the question, I think you don't like the `nqpsk2` solution (which is fastest) in my answer. The top of the answer  (where is says **Summary**) details a one line solution. Both are for blocks and the first paragraph explains why blocks are important for speed.

Comment: ,@DanGetz : And blocks are Julia's problem, I'm interested in single values. In my applications, a huge vector is already there, I just fill it in place, single value at a time. BTW, I get different timings from those you posted, I get: `@btime nqpsk1(320);
  2.680 μs (1 allocation: 5.13 KiB)

@btime nqpsk2(320);
  3.239 μs (3 allocations: 5.20 KiB)`. Can you double-check using `@time` instead?.

Comment: @Don So, you do need a block of values, but the block's memory is already allocated. This is an advantage. Instead of the one-liner at top of answer do: `for (b1,b2,i) in zip(rand!(BitVector(N)),rand!(BitVector(N)),1:N) sig[i] = (-1)^b1*im^b2 ; end`. I assumed the vector is named `sig` like in the question and filled it. With practice and by reading  [Julia Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/), Julia will become quite similar to C++ in performance and capability (but more friendly in my opinion).

Answer (score -3):

**Latest state of investigation**

My current best solution is the following:

```
function g(pX::Array{Complex{Float64},1})
    tab = [1.0,im,-1.0,-im]
    bits = UInt128(0)
    @inbounds for i = 1 : length(pX)
        bits = (i % 64) == 1 ? rand(UInt128) : bits >>> 2
        pX[i] = tab[(bits & 3)+1]
    end
end

sig = complex(zeros(1280));
using BenchmarkTools
@btime g(sig)

3.838 μs (13 allocations: 464 bytes)
```

This is better than my optimized version of Dan Getz which runs with the same N, and i feel much more readable

```
4.236 μs (4 allocations: 20.16 KiB)
```

However, the performance is extremely fragil. Just have a look at subtle differences to this **36 times slower** version:

```
function g(pX::Array{Complex{Float64},1})
    tab = [1,im,-1,-im]
    bits = 0
    for i = 1 : length(pX)
        bits = (i % 64) == 1 ? rand(UInt128) : bits >>> 2
        pX[i] = tab[(bits & 3)+1]
    end
end

138.320 μs (10209 allocations: 319.14 KiB)
```

Did you find the differences?

- no conversion from Int64 to Float64
- Type stability
- disable range checking

to follow the convention g() should be renamed to g!()

In the following you find the evolution to the currently best timed solution

---

My first approach to answer was addressing general weaknesses

a) calling functions is expensive due to calling overhead.

b) complex calculations are more time consuming than lookup.

This end up with the proposal

```
 cases = [1+0im,0+1im,-1+0im,0-1im]
 g() = cases[rand(1:4)]
 // to use just call g() 
 g()
```

**What happend?**

**Why does a) do not succeed?**

```
using BenchmarkTools
test(n) = [q() for i = 1:n]

g() = rand()
@btime test(800);
```

This results to

- rand() => 5.784
- rand(Float32) => 5.604
- rand(Float64) => 5.821
- rand(Bool) => 5.167
- rand(Int8) => 5.126
- rand(Int16) => 5.171
- rand(Int32) => 5.631
- rand(Int64) => 7.980
- rand(Int128) => 10.549
- rand(1:4) => 28.603
- (rand(Int8) % 4) + 1 => 6.053
- (rand(Int8) & 3) + 1 => 5.843
- rand(0:255) => 28.568
- rand(UInt8) => 5.104
- rand([1,2,3,4]) => 58.437
- l = [1,2,3,4]; g() = rand(l)  => 47.399
- rand(l, 1) => 70.052
- m = (1,2,3,4); rand(m) => 124.311
- 0 => 0.872
- 0.0 => 0.887
- Int8(0) => 0.113
- return => 0.33

(running Julia 0.6 on Ubuntu)

**How to judge the results**

requesting float32 and float64 needs same time. This may be an indicator that float64 does NOT the full mantisse (of 56 bits) for random value

rand for Bool, Int8, Int16 needs nearly the same time. Probably same algorithmus just using fewer bits.

rand for Int32 slightly more time consuming. Int64 and Int128 takes under proportional more time.

rand(1:4) takes surprisingly much more time. It should be in the range of rand(Int8) since it is equivalent to (rand(Int8) % 4) + 1 and (rand(Int8) & 3) + 1.
Even if I hurt somebodies religious feelings, this is just poor code.

Same to rand(Uint) and rand(0:255)

The performance of rand with arrays and tupel is far from acceptable!

**Why does b) do not succeed?**

Julia seems not able to lookup efficiently from tupels or arrays.
But even when lookup were fast, the rand methods dominates.

**Other approaches**

**Dan Getz approach** uses all bits from a rand call. So in end it needs in his first algorithm 1/16 calls per value.

However, this approach could be improved by using UInt128 since now 1/64 calls per value is required.

On my machine Dan Getz original code takes 17.314 for 1280 values while the modified code takes 4.595. The improvement is proportional to the reduced number of calls to rand!

```
test2(n::Int) = begin
    res = zeros(Int,2*n)
    blocks = n >>> 7                 # use blocks of 16 values
    btail = n & 0x000000000000007f   # in case n is not a multiple of 16
    pos = 1
    @inbounds for i=1:blocks
        bits = rand(UInt128)          # get random bits for a whole block
        for j=1:16
            b1 = Bool(bits & 1)
            bits >>>= 1
            b2 = Bool(bits & 1)
            bits >>>= 1
            res[pos+b1] = (-1)^b2
            pos += 2
        end
    end
    @inbounds for i=1:btail
        res[pos+rand(Bool)] = (-1)^rand(Bool)
        pos += 2
    end
    return reinterpret(Complex{Int64},res)
end

@btime test2(1280);
```

However, the use of **reinterpret** means to know the bit layout of the different structures. That not a real good idea.

**high level view**

In the end all what the questioneer has coded was a complicated complex build array of random numbers from 1 to 4 (or 0 to 3). I would try to optimize the next step in questioneers following task. However, no info were supplied.

In that following case julia performs much better, which sounds somewhat strange. More returns, less time??

```
@btime rand(0:3, 1280)
=> 24.377
```

PS:
Just for comparing the numbers with Dan Getz last approach, the following code takes 27.004

```
N=1280
@btime [(-1)^b1*im^b2 for (b1,b2) in zip(rand!(BitVector(N)),rand!(BitVector(N)))]
```

Comment: `rand(::Bool)` is a different operation than `rand(::UnitRange{Int})` because of julias multiple dispatch, and a lot faster. This is not something wrong with the compiler, it is a property of the language. Your `cases[rand(1:4)]` code allocates, since you use array slicing. Julia is easy and fast - the default choice `rand(cases,1)` is fast and very clear. But you CAN make it even faster, and that is what the question is about.

Comment: I am sorry, but a GOOD compiler will be able to resolve rand(1:4) to code like something as (rand(Int8)&3)+1. Multiple dispatch should be a compiler/language feature but not (neccessarily) an implementation style.

Comment: But should a good compiler make rand(1:4) faster than calling rand(Bool) twice? What's the underlying implementation logic of that?

Comment: @stefanbachert -- (+1) for saying the truth (_rand seems to be implemented rather poor_), and yes, I didn't  just call "rand(1:4)" because I know that `rand(Bool)` is way faster. PS: I'm sorry, I can't upvote now!

Comment: @Michael K.Borregaard: a single call should in general be faster than twice calls which is not true in julia as I documented in the above answer. eq. rand(Uint) much faster than rand(0:255)